# refactoring rails redirects with multiple ifs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In the app I am working on, the user can get to a new form from several different places. I need to redirect them back to where they came from. I solved it by passing a parameter in the link on the view, for example

```
= link_to "create a new post »", new_user_post_path(@current_user, :return_to => 'dashboard')
```

then in the new action in the controller like so

```
if params[:return_to] == 'dashboard'
  session[:return_to]= 'dashboard'
end
```

now I am looking at the controller. what I need to do I can achieve by being really verbose, but I'm looking for a more elegant solution. Here is what I have now

```
if @user_post.save
  flash[:notice] = "New Post Created"
  if session[:return_to] == 'dashboard'
    session.delete(:return_to)
    redirect_to dashboard_path and return
  else
  redirect_to user_hub_path(@user)
 end
else
  flash[:error] = "Could not save post"
  redirect_to new_user_post_path(@user)
end
```

This does what I need but I was hoping to tidy it up a little. I started looking at 1 line enumerators to see if I could do something like this...

```
if @user_post.save
  flash[:notice] = "New post Created"
  session[:return_to] == 'dashboard' ? redirect_to "#{session.delete(:return_to)}_path" : redirect_to user_hub_path(@user)
else
  flash[:error] = "Could not save post"
  redirect_to new_user_post_path(@user)
end
```

but it really doesn't like this part....redirect_to "#{session.delete(:return_to)}_path"

any advice? Guess I'm trying to get it to redirect and delete the session in one line and this is beyond my knowledge...

Comment: Why not passing the direct url with `return_to` param?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a good case for using Rails' built-in `:back` parameter, which, according to the Rails docs [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html), sends the user "Back to the page that issued the request. Useful for forms that are triggered from multiple places. Short-hand for redirect_to(request.env["HTTP_REFERER"])"

You can avoid passing a `return_to` param, and change your controller code to:

```
if @user_post.save
  redirect_to :back, notice: "New Post Created" and return
else
  redirect_to new_user_post_path(@user), flash: { error: "Could not save post" }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using `send`?

`send` takes a message name and optional arguments and forwards that to send's receiver (http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-send)

```
path = send("#{session.delete(:return_to)}_path")
redirect_to path
```

In this case it sends the message to the current controller instance (same as just calling the `..._path` method but gives the flexibility of the dynamic call)

Answer (score 0):

Please instead of using a redirect_to variable of your controller, use the [Referer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) Header.

> HTTP referer (originally a misspelling of referrer) is an HTTP header field that identifies the address of the webpage (i.e. the URI or IRI) that linked to the resource being requested

In Rails is quite simple inside a controller

```
redirect_to request.referer
```

That is more elegant and efficient, because the session cookie storage can be expensive (cache storage) and could affect your HTTP cache proxies performance.